# Can I set Outlook to always open in Shortcuts view?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

Is it possible to set Outlook (2007 and/or 2010) to always open in Shortcuts view on the left hand side? (I see from [this link](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/start-outlook-in-the-folder-list-or-shortcuts-view-HA001118248.aspx) that it is possible in 2003.)

Ideally it would be a registry setting but failing that a command line option will do. I have tried doing

```
outlook.exe /select outlook:shortcuts
```

but that did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be honest, I don't think so any more. I just played with that registry key, and changed the values from 0-9, but in each case, unless it was set to 0 or 5, it gave me my Favorites, not Shortcuts as in 2003.

The /select switch lets you select a folder, but "Shortcuts" is not a folder, so it does not work.

I think the best bet may be to add your Shortcuts as Favorites instead (and set the registry value to 6). That might be as close as you get, and it seems pretty close to me, at least for Outlook folders...Internet shortcuts are another story.

Hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>, then right click any of the folders at the bottom you want to add to your Favorites.

Answer (score 0):

If you navigate to the shortcuts menu, click file and save outlook will remember your last view and open this way